# Is there any quick way to switch between relative layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say I have an XML with this structure:

```
FrameLayout
    RelativeLayout (on whole screen)
        Buttons, Texts etc.
    RelativeLayout (on whole screen)
        Buttons, Texts etc.
```

On the 'Design' or 'Preview' tab I always see the first relative layout that I created. I've been switching between them by making the other one invisible but it is a mess when you have more than two layouts. Is there any option in Android that provides this functionality, I mean switching between different layouts in one XML?

Comment: Fragments? You replace the entire layout using a FragmentTransaction

Comment: I don't mean code-wise, I just need to switch between layouts on design tab.

Comment: Tap the shift key twice... Type the name of the XML file you want to open?

Comment: Search is not helping since both relative layouts are in the same XML file.

Comment: Well, it's been said multiple times now that you should use Fragments and two layouts. Xml files are cheap resources, so there is no reason not to separate the two relative layouts and swap fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android Studio you can't view both RelativeLayouts at the same time properly if they are both filling your screen. I suggest you to use two xml's containing the RelativeLayout to design them to your needs. After that you can easily merge them into one xml. For example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <include android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout="@layout/your_first_relativelayout" />
    <include android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" layout="@layout/your_second_relativelayout" />
</FrameLayout>
```

If you want to hide or show a layout programmaticly, you should assign both your RelativeLayouts an unique id, like this:

your_first_relativelayout.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/your_relative_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        ....
    </RelativeLayout>
```

To show it:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_relative_layout_id);
if (rl != null) {
    rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And hiding it:

```
rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not option.
It is better to use two layout file and swith them in editor.
(And two layout file will be included form original layout file by using `<include>` tag)